# SSJS: How to create an email and keep the personalization strings as variables?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, soap-api, ssjs

I’m stuck trying to create an email with SSJS.  I have the email being created in the account, but the required personalization strings (e.g. %%profile_center%%) in the HTMLBody and TextBody values are being evaluated during creation.  So when I go into the account after the SSJS processes, I see the actual profile center URL, when I want to see the variable with percent signs still.  Have you run into this?

Here is my code:

```
var HTMLBody = "";
HTMLBody += '<b>This is a test email</b>';
HTMLBody += '<a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a>';
HTMLBody += 'This email was sent by: %%Member_Busname%%';
HTMLBody += '%%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%';

var TextBody = HTMLBody.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");

var EmailConfig = {
                CustomerKey:"Email",
                Name:"Email",
                Subject:"Some Email",
                HTMLBody:HTMLBody,
                TextBody:TextBody,
                IsActive:"true",
                IsHTMLPaste:"true",
                Status:"active",    
                EmailType:"HTML",
                CharacterSet:"US-ASCII",
                HasDynamicSubjectLine:"false"
};
var NewEmail = Email.Add(EmailConfig);
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the evaluated AMPScript?  It shouldn't evaluate unless you're doing a Send or Send Preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this on a landing page, then I'd try concatenating the double percents separately.

```
var HTMLBody = "";
HTMLBody += '<b>This is a test email</b>';
HTMLBody += '<a href="' + '%%' + 'profile_center_url' + '%%' + '" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a>';
HTMLBody += 'This email was sent by: ' + '%%' + 'Member_Busname' + '%%';
HTMLBody += '%%' + 'Member_Addr' + '%%' + ', ' + '%%' + 'Member_City' + '%%' + ', ';
HTMLBody += '%%' + 'Member_State' + '%%' + ', ' + '%%' + 'Member_PostalCode' + '%%' + ', ' + '%%' + 'Member_Country' + '%%';

var TextBody = HTMLBody.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");

var EmailConfig = {
                CustomerKey:"Email",
                Name:"Email",
                Subject:"Some Email",
                HTMLBody:HTMLBody,
                TextBody:TextBody,
                IsActive:"true",
                IsHTMLPaste:"true",
                Status:"active",    
                EmailType:"HTML",
                CharacterSet:"US-ASCII",
                HasDynamicSubjectLine:"false"
};
var NewEmail = Email.Add(EmailConfig);
```

Comment: Adam, great job solving this.  I didn't even see the landing page being the issue.  I tested this and it works like a charm!  Thank you.

Comment: @Adam I am supposed to find the email in the emails list after executing this scripts successfully, I tried to that but when i am searching the email message with its name, I am not finding anything ?

Comment: @Michael are you able to find the email message in the Content Builder ?